# Вытащить определенное значение из массива в Java

Tags: java

подскажите не знаю каким способом или методом можно правильно вытащить значение из массива в моем случае. У меня есть массив **car** имеющий значения в формате **C(CODE_CAR)_гос номер-пробег-(доп. параметр)**. Мне необходимо вытащить эти **доп. параметры** и поместить их в новый массив, если у какого-то элемента нет доп. параметра, то тогда вносим 0. У меня есть рабочая реализация решения написанная мной на JavaScript, где я своим возможно костыльным методом с помощью **split** вытаскиваю эти последние значения доп. параметра, но в таком случае он вносит underfined. Если этого доп. параметра нет, то я его затем в дальнейшем меняю пробежавшись по массиву на 0.

Вот часть не рабочего кода, где я думал пробежаться по массиву и затем внутреннему массиву, чтобы узнать есть ли у него два тире, что подтверждает о наличии доп. параметра

```java
String[] car = new String[] {"C100_1-100", "C200_1-120-1200", "C300_1-120-30", "C400_1-80-20", "C100_2-50", "C200_2-40-1000", "C300_2-200-45", "C400_2-10-20", "C100_3-10", "C200_3-170-1100", "C300_3-150-29", "C400_3-100-28", "C100_1-300", "C200_1-100-750", "C300_1-32-15"};

ArrayList<String> car_argument = new ArrayList<String>(); // отдельный лист с доп. параметром
int k; //  хотел сделать счетчик для проверки наличии двух тире и дальнейшего обнуления по новому кругу
for(int i = 0; i < car.length; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < car.length; j++){
    if(car[i][j] == '-'){
      k = k+1;
      if(k == 2){
        car_argument.add(car[i].split("-")[2])
        k = 0;
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

А вот рабочий код на JavaScript, который я пробую сделать на Java

```js
let car = ["C100_1-100", "C200_1-120-1200", "C300_1-120-30", "C400_1-80-20", "C100_2-50", "C200_2-40-1000", "C300_2-200-45", "C400_2-10-20", "C100_3-10", "C200_3-170-1100", "C300_3-150-29", "C400_3-100-28", "C100_1-300", "C200_1-100-750", "C300_1-32-15"];
let car_argument = []; // отдельный массив с доп. параметром
 
// заносим доп. параметр всех авто в отдельный массив вместе с underfined
  for(let i = 0; i < car.length; i++){
    car_argument.push(car[i].split("-")[2])
  }
  // Если доп. параметра в массиве нет, то заменим на 0 наш underfined
  
  for(let i = 0; i < car_argument.length; i++){
    if(typeof(car_argument[i]) == 'undefined'){
      car_argument[i] = 0;
    }
    else{
      car_argument[i] = Number(car_argument[i]) // преобразуем строку в число
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Принципиальная ошибка здесь

```java
for(int j = 0; j < car.length; j++){
```

Вы запускаете второй цикл по элементам массива `car` вместо того, чтобы запустить его по символам конкретного элемента

```java
for(int j = 0; j < car[i].length(); j++){
```

Потом если программу подрихтовать, сделать правильный доступ к отдельному символу, учесть отсутствие кода, то получится такой код

```java
String[] car = new String[] {"C100_1-100", "C200_1-120-1200", "C300_1-120-30", "C400_1-80-20", "C100_2-50", "C200_2-40-1000", "C300_2-200-45", "C400_2-10-20", "C100_3-10", "C200_3-170-1100", "C300_3-150-29", "C400_3-100-28", "C100_1-300", "C200_1-100-750", "C300_1-32-15"};

ArrayList<String> car_argument = new ArrayList<String>(); // отдельный лист с доп. параметром
for(int i = 0; i < car.length; i++){
  int k = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < car[i].length(); j++){
    if(car[i].charAt(j) == '-'){
      k++;
      if (k == 2) {
        car_argument.add(car[i].split("-")[2]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (k < 2)
    car_argument.add("0");
}
```

Если же убрать совершенно не нужный перебор символов, то код сильно сократится

```java
String[] car = new String[] {"C100_1-100", "C200_1-120-1200", "C300_1-120-30", "C400_1-80-20", "C100_2-50", "C200_2-40-1000", "C300_2-200-45", "C400_2-10-20", "C100_3-10", "C200_3-170-1100", "C300_3-150-29", "C400_3-100-28", "C100_1-300", "C200_1-100-750", "C300_1-32-15"};

ArrayList<String> car_argument = new ArrayList<String>(); // отдельный лист с доп. параметром
for(int i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
    String[] parts = car[i].split("-");
    if (parts.length == 3)
        car_argument.add(parts[2]);
    else
        car_argument.add("0");
}
```

Comment: Пардон. У меня, видимо, палец дернулся.